# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty on line 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have read plenty on this subject but i dont understand why it wouldnt be working the way im doing it. im instantiating my new post in my posts_controller. I am using rails 4. would that matter?

here is my controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @posts = Post.all     
  end

  def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
      @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      if @post.save
          redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post was saved"
      else
          render ="new"
      end
  end

  private
  def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

  def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

      if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
          redirect_to Posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been updated"
      else
          render "edit"
      end
  end

  def destroy

  end
end
```

here is what i have in my edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %> <br/>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :content %> <br/>
        <%= f.text_area :content %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Update Post" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Why would it say that my @post is nil?
i tried doing "form_for Post.new do |f|" and this works. but i have heard this is not a good approach

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `edit`, `update` and `destroy` actions as `private`. Because of which those actions are not getting called while rendering the specific view, `@post` variable is not set. Hence, you get the error. Remove them from the private section and add them as public.

`PostsController` should look as below:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @posts = Post.all     
  end

  def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
      @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      if @post.save
          redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Your post was saved"
      else
          render ="new"
      end
  end

  def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

      if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
          redirect_to Posts_path, :notice => "Your post has been updated"
      else
          render "edit"
      end
  end

  def destroy
     ## You would need the below code for deleting a post
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     @post.destroy
     redirect_to roles_url 
  end

  private
  def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! i cant believe how easy that was. its always the easy stuff